# Refresh EF context after synchronize with SyncFramework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm developing a WPF application with EF6 and SyncFramework 2.1 to synchronize data from and to a SQLServer. I don't know if it is a good practice or how should I refresh the EF context after the download sync is finished...

I don't know which data has been synchronized, so.. should I refresh all the context?

Answer (score 0):

you can subscribe to the Changes Applied event and you can get access to what changes has been synched. or simply refresh the entire context rather than looping thru each change and refreshing.

Comment: The easiest way is refresh the entire context but didn't know if it is a bad practice. Subscribing that event I must do too much logic. Can you explain me how to refresh the entire context? I've seen some examples but they aren't working